# Does GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint() return the GUID of a volume?

Tags: windows, guid, disk, volume

Does GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint() return the GUID of a volume in c++?

```
GetVolumeNameForVolumeMmountPoint()
{
LPCTSTR lpszvolumeMountPoint,
LPTSTR lpszVolumeName,
DWORDcchBufferLength,
}
```

I mean if I am using a removeable disk. will the lpszVolumeName remained the same on the same computer?
Does it return a certain ID for a certain volume everytime I insert the disk on my computer' USBport.
And Make sure different disk's volumes will get different result?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567603%28VS.85%29.aspx) about the mount manager that states the GUID is permanently associated with the volume and it is persisted across system restarts.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN call volumename as GUID, but it's not the case.
I test it with following step:

1. clone DiskA to DiskB with ORICO USB HDD Dock;
2. Connect only DiskA to PC with HDD Dock, WinXP assign letter 'G' to it and GUID is {ea044c37-816f-11e3-bea8-005056c00008}, as register shows

   ```
   "\\DosDevices\\G:"=hex:a7,5e,f9,19,00,7e,00,00,00,00,00,00
   "\\??\\Volume{ea044c37-816f-11e3-bea8-005056c00008}"=hex:a7,5e,f9,19,00,7e,00,\
   ```
3. Replace DiskA with DiskB and connect it to PC, driver letter is the same 'G', and GUID is the same {ea044c37-816f-11e3-bea8-005056c00008};
4. Connect both DiskA and DiskB with HDD Dock(2 Bays), then DiskB's GUID changed to {ea044c39-816f-11e3-bea8-005056c00008}